# How to replace the for with a while loop

Tags: python

How can I change the `for` loop into a `while` loop. What are the significant differences between using `for` and `while` loop?

```
S="I had a cat named amanda when I was little"
count = 0
for i in S:
    if i =="a":
        count += 1
print (count)
```

Comment: Have you come up with some way?

Comment: Why do you want a `while` loop at all? This `for` loop looks nice (even though the whole thing could be replaced by `count = S.count('a')`)

Comment: @nneonneo: My guess is this is a homework assignment, that's why he wish to make the change :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the while loop implementation of same code.

```
i = 0
count = 0
while i < len(S):
    if S[i] == 'a':
        count += 1
    i += 1
print count
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a counter which will be incremented each time "while counter < len(S)"

Here's a start:

```
index = 0
count = 0
while index < len(S):
    #do something with index and S ...
    index += 1
```

Comment: you could use `index` name instead of `counter` to avoid confusion

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- Yeah.  I suppose I will.  I went back and forth on the name of that for a while.  I ultimately settled on `counter` because that's what it's doing -- and it's a relatively common name for a variable used in a loop like this in other languages.  I also sort of wanted OP to figure out that `counter` would end up being the index for himself ... I never know how much to give in questions like these ... Anyway, you're probably right.  It's probably best to post clear code on SO, rather than somewhat vague code in the hopes that OP will figure out the meaning themself ...

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it via the boolean nature of an empty string/list/dictionary.

```
S="I had a cat named amanda when I was little"
count = 0
while S:
    # pop the first character off of the string
    ch, S = S[0], S[1:]
    if ch == "a":
        count += 1
print (count)
```

Comment: And if you really want to be clever, you can get rid of `if` -- `count += ch == 'a'`.  But that's more clever than it should be ... (just mentioning it for fun, not because I think you should use it).

Comment: That's a whole different world - ``len(filter(lambda c: c == 'a', S))``

Comment: Hadn't realized that the [...] were optional in that case, cool

Comment: without `[]`, it is a generator expression.  Typically, you need `()` around them, but as a special case, you can omit the parenthesis when the generator expression is the only argument to the function.